# Calculate the Burning Time for a Lamp

Tags: self-learning, exponentiation, exponential-function

If you have a lamp with burning time 4000 hours. If the time goes forward until the lamp will be destroyed the exponential distribution is 3675 hours, what is the probability of a lamp to be working at least 4000 hours?

I don't know how to calculate in order to achieve the result?

I have read the [document](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~riczw/stat330s11/lecture/lec13.pdf) about calculation but still I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ then $P[X\geqslant x]=\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}$. The time during which the lamp is working has the statistical properties of $X$ for $\lambda^{-1}=3675$ hours. Use this for $x=4000$ hours.

Comment: This assumes that "If the time goes forward until the lamp will be destroyed the exponential distribution is 3675 hours" actually means "If the lamp is destroyed after a random time whose distribution is exponential with mean 3675 hours".

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have some questions. If I understand correctly the answer would be                               e−λx    >>    e-λ4000 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the value of λ do not exist and how should I calculate it based on formula "e−λx"?

Comment: "the value of λ do(es) not exist"... Sorry? Why do you think so?

Comment: Maybe another way how achieve it but how, I don't how. Im newbie in statistics

Comment: The value of $\lambda$ is in my post.